# Paste with space inserted before text

Tags: cut-copy-paste, normal-mode

Is there a command to paste (`p`) text with space inserted before that text like in `join`?

I don't want to achieve that by mapping.

Normally <kbd>p</kbd> pastes text right **in** the cursor's position in Normal Mode.

Switching modes, and inserting space manually everytime can be frustrating.

Answer (score 5):

As you have stated in your question, you don't want to use a new mapping for this. (I'm also more in favour of "vanilla" vim key-bindings if possible, so I can use my muscle-memory on other systems aswell)

The following vim keys let you paste with an additional `space`, without the need to leave insert mode for pasting:

a) Paste after a word somewhere in the middle of the line

1. go to end of word with `e`
2. press `a` to go into insert mode directly after word
3. press `space` to insert space after last character
4. press `CTRL-r` (cursor turns into `"`)
5. press `"` for the last copy register (or `0` for the second-to-last, or `+` for system clipboard register,...) **(*)**

b) Paste at the end of current line

1. press `A` to go directly into insert mode at the end of line
2. press `space`
3. press `CTRL-r` (cursor turns into `"`)
4. select preferred register **(*)**

**(*)** To see all the copy registers use the command `:registers`

Also, `:help i_CTRL-R` might be worth a read.

Answer (score 4):

Use `@p`.

Prerequisite: .vimrc needs to contain this line (add it):

`let @p='i ^[p'`

You're saying: when I press `@p` you

- press `i` for me so that you enter INSERT mode, then
- insert a space, then
- press ESC (`^[` means ESC) to get back to NORMAL mode, then
- press `p` to do the paste.

You're in NORMAL mode when it's done.

**In case you haven't worked with registers yet**

`p` is a register. Think of a macro consisting of anything you could do with your hands using the basic vim commands, typing and switching modes included.

Use the `q` command to define register contents (the `recording` status in the left bottom corner is for that).

Comment: This seems to literally insert "^[" into the text. Is there some special escaping I need to apply to .vimrc?

Comment: @CharlieDalsass You can insert a literal escape with `Ctrl-v Esc` or `Ctrl-v Ctrl-[`.

Comment: @CharlieDalsass, alternatively, you can use one of Vim's "special characters" for this: `:let @p = "i \<Esc>p"`

Comment: @Rich, thanks I was having trouble with the escaping so I came up with the solution below. Didn't realize it was that simple!

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm gonna start using registers on a daily basis thanks to your answer. Real thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In .vimrc use a leader key and specify as follows:

`nnoremap <leader>p li<space><esc>p`

(leader-P to insert buffer after the cursor, adding a single space before the buffer.)